# R gt package - How to rename all columns at once

Tags: r, gt, r-colnames

I have a dataframe like this one:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)
library(gtExtras)

test = dplyr::tibble(
  id = 1:3,
  type1_value1 = 2:4,
  type1_value2 = 3:5,
  type2_value1 = 4:6,
  type2_value2 = 5:7)
```

I actually want to have only spanners but no col_lables, which doesnt seem to work, when I try it:

```
test %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "span1",
    columns = c(2:3)) %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "span2",
    columns = c(4:5)) %>%
  tab_options(column_labels.hidden = TRUE)
```

The spanners just wont appear. If you know any solution what is wrong, please give me a hint.
I tried to work around it now by just renaming every column with no name.

```
test %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "span1",
    columns = c(2:3)) %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "span2",
    columns = c(4:5)) %>%
  cols_label(id = "", type1_value1 = "", type1_value2 = "", 
             type2_value1 = "", type2_value2 = "") 
  
  cols_label(id = "", type1_value1 = "", type1_value2 = "", 
             type2_value1 = "", type2_value2 = "")
```

My real df has over 200 columns. How can I rename them all at once? They should all get the empty name "".

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `tidyselect` helper `everything()` you could rename all columns at once like so:

```
library(gt)
library(tidyverse)

test %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "span1",
    columns = c(2:3)
  ) %>%
  tab_spanner(
    label = "span2",
    columns = c(4:5)
  ) %>%
  cols_label(
    everything() ~ ""
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that already, but I am getting an error: Error in `cols_label()`:
! Named arguments are required for `cols_label()`.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: Hm. Most likely an issue with version(s). I'm using `gt` `‘0.9.0’`.

Comment: You are correct! I updated gt and now it works fine! Thanks a lot!